# Generate html elements on based of json type

Tags: html, mongodb, meteor

I want to create html elements on the base of json type. I am getting value from database. I want to check in json value type is text then it should generate textbox. If it is radio then it should generate radio box. I am using code.

```
<template name="dpVar">
    <ul>
        <h1>varienats</h1> {{#each variant}}

        <table>
            {{#each VARIENTS}}
            <tr>
                <td>
                    {{this.NAME}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text">
                </td>
            </tr>
            {{/each}}
        </table>

        {{/each}}
    </ul>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [json2html](http://json2html.com).  It's a javascript HTML templating library used to transform JSON objects into HTML using a user-specified JSON transform.